# issues creating an array php

Tags: php

I'm writing a PHP application, and one of the features is be able to query gene interactions in all our tables `(gene_r, genes_newL_dn, genes_newL_up, genes_oldL_up, genes_oldL_dn)`.
So I have the following `PHP` function to query all those databases at once.

```
public function getAllInteractions($input){
    $data = array();

    $sql_list = (
        "SELECT * FROM genes_r JOIN drugs_r ON drugs_r.id = genes_r.id WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'",
        "SELECT * FROM genes_newL_dn JOIN drugs_newL_dn ON drugs_newL_dn.id = genes_newL_dn WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'",
        "SELECT * FROM genes_newL_up JOIN drugs_newL_up ON drugs_newL_up.id = genes_newL_up WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'",
        "SELECT * FROM genes_oldL_dn JOIN drugs_oldL_dn ON drugs_oldL_dn.id = genes_oldL_dn WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'",
        "SELECT * FROM genes_oldL_up JOIN drugs_oldL_up ON drugs_oldL_up.id = genes_oldL_up WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'"
    );

    foreach($sql_list as $sql){
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        // case 1 : SQL Query invalid / empty results
        if(!$query || $query->num_rows() == 0) {
            continue;   
        }
        else {
            $id = $query->row()->id;
            $sql = "SELECT interaction from matrix_r WHERE id='$id'";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            array_push($data, $query->row());
        }   
    }

    return $data;
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ',' in 
/chemicalgenomics/ci/application/models/search_model.php on line 81
```

I'm not getting why does not like the ','. It's supposed to be an array of strings. Could someone please help me with that?
Thanks

PS: `Line 81` is the first line in the array: `"SELECT * FROM ...`

Answer (score 5):

You initialize the array wrong, you need to place the `array` at the begining:

```
$sql_list = array(
    "SELECT * FROM genes_r JOIN drugs_r ON drugs_r.id = genes_r.id WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'",
    "SELECT * FROM genes_newL_dn JOIN drugs_newL_dn ON drugs_newL_dn.id = genes_newL_dn WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'",
    "SELECT * FROM genes_newL_up JOIN drugs_newL_up ON drugs_newL_up.id = genes_newL_up WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'",
    "SELECT * FROM genes_oldL_dn JOIN drugs_oldL_dn ON drugs_oldL_dn.id = genes_oldL_dn WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'",
    "SELECT * FROM genes_oldL_up JOIN drugs_oldL_up ON drugs_oldL_up.id = genes_oldL_up WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'"
);
```

If you have PHP 5.4 or greater (not that many web hosts do however), you can use the new short array syntax which you were close to, but the character is a bracket (`[`) rather than a parenthesis (`(`):

```
$sql_list = [
    "SELECT ...",
    "SELECT ...",
];
```

Answer (score 1):

`$sql_list = array(x, y, z);` is the right syntax for PHP arrays. So, in your code, it should be:

```
$sql_list = array(
    "SELECT * FROM genes_r JOIN drugs_r ON drugs_r.id = genes_r.id WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'",
    "SELECT * FROM genes_newL_dn JOIN drugs_newL_dn ON drugs_newL_dn.id = genes_newL_dn WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'",
    "SELECT * FROM genes_newL_up JOIN drugs_newL_up ON drugs_newL_up.id = genes_newL_up WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'",
    "SELECT * FROM genes_oldL_dn JOIN drugs_oldL_dn ON drugs_oldL_dn.id = genes_oldL_dn WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'",
    "SELECT * FROM genes_oldL_up JOIN drugs_oldL_up ON drugs_oldL_up.id = genes_oldL_up WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'"
);
```

If you are using PHP 5.4, there's shortened syntax available:

```
$sql_list = [
    "SELECT * FROM genes_r JOIN drugs_r ON drugs_r.id = genes_r.id WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'",
    "SELECT * FROM genes_newL_dn JOIN drugs_newL_dn ON drugs_newL_dn.id = genes_newL_dn WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'",
    "SELECT * FROM genes_newL_up JOIN drugs_newL_up ON drugs_newL_up.id = genes_newL_up WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'",
    "SELECT * FROM genes_oldL_dn JOIN drugs_oldL_dn ON drugs_oldL_dn.id = genes_oldL_dn WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'",
    "SELECT * FROM genes_oldL_up JOIN drugs_oldL_up ON drugs_oldL_up.id = genes_oldL_up WHERE drug_name='$input' OR gene_name='$input'"
];
```